# How do I go about getting the current id of a local MongoDB I created?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Basically, I'm trying to compare the user's answer for a question in a "null" or local MongoDB to a key in another MongoDB that was declared before.

I know that to get the _id of the declared MongoDB (the real databse) is to call this._id, which is evident when I run console log on the browser console.

But how can I retrieve the _id of the local MongoDB?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is the helper code:

```
    Template.question.events({
  "click .button": function(e){
    e.preventDefault;


    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName("choices").length; i++){

      if (document.getElementsByName("choices")[i].checked){
        var init = document.getElementsByName("choices")[i].value;
      }
    }
    Answers.insert({answer: init});

    if(Answers.find({answer: init}) === Quiz.find({_id: this._id}, {answer: init})){
      console.log("The answers match.");
    }
  }

});
```

The last part of the code is me attempting to compare the answer field in the "Answers" DB, which is the local DB to the answers field in the Quiz DB, which is the declared, legitimate database.

**Edit:**

So I used user "gdataDan" suggestion and changed my code to include a function taking in the error and result parameters + I added an else statement to see if the event helper actually is functioning properly until the end:

```
Template.question.helpers({
  title: function(){
    return Quiz.find();
  }
})

Template.question.events({
  "click .button": function(e){
    e.preventDefault;


    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName("choices").length; i++){

      if (document.getElementsByName("choices")[i].checked){
        var init = document.getElementsByName("choices")[i].value;
      }
    }

    var id = "";

    Answers.insert({answer: init}, function(error, result){
      if (error){
        console.log("error: " + error);
      } else if (result){
        id = result;
      }
    })

    if(Answers.find({_id: id}, {answer: init}) === Quiz.find({_id: this._id}, {answer: init})){
      console.log("The answers match.");
    } else {
      console.log("Something went wrong.");
    }
  }

});
```

Turns out that console log prints "Something went wrong," even though the answers match between both databases. So I feel like the way I call the find function or the id's themselves don't match.

**Edit#2:**

I tried declaring the init variable outside the loop and tried using the $eq operator for MongoDB and still get the "Something went wrong" message in the console.

Comment: Do you have some code or pseudocode to explain your logic? Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Per your second question as to why the answers do not match it is because you are using find which returns a cursor of the data and not the data itself. The cursors are not the same. Try using findOne on both queries. Example: var myanswers = Answers.findOne(id,{fields:{answer:init}}); You can then access the data directly. Also, please try running these queries in your browser console to see what sort of output they provide. This will help you in writing your comparison code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[collection.insert](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/insert) will return the ID if there is no error.

```
var id = ''
Answers.insert({answer: init},function(error,result){
if(error) console.log('error: ' + error);
if(result) id = result;
});
```